# Spivak: $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ on $[-1,1]$. $\mathscr{L}(x)$ defined as length of $f$ on $[x,1]$. Show $\mathscr{L}(x)=\int_x^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, derivatives, proof-explanation

The following problem is from Ch. 15 of Spivak's *Calculus*. I show my attempted solution with a question, and then try to interpret the solution from the solution manual, with another question about that.

> *28. This problem gives a treatment of the trigonometric functions in terms of length, and uses Problem 13-25. Let $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ for
> $-1\leq x\leq 1$.
>
> Define $\mathscr{L}(x)$ to be the length of $f$ on $[x,1]$.
>
> (a) Show that
>
> $$\mathscr{L}(x)=\int_x^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt\tag{1}$$

**Here is my attempt at a solution**

In Problem 13-25 we are asked to show that the length of a function $f$ on $[a,b]$ is $\int_a^b \sqrt{1+(f'(t))^2}dt$ if the integrand is integrable on $[a,b]$.

For our $f$ we have

$$f'(x)=\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

$$\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Therefore, if $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ is integrable on $[x,1]$ then $(1)$ is the length of $f$ on $[x,1]$.

The integral in $(1)$ is improper since $\arcsin'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ is unbounded near $1$.

I believe this improper integral can be defined as

$$\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 1^-} \int_x^{\epsilon} \arcsin'(t)dt$$

**If we compute this limit, is that sufficient to prove that $(1)$ is true?**

**Spivak's solution manual does something different**

> length of $f$ on $[x,1-\epsilon]$
>
> $$=\int_x^{1-\epsilon} \sqrt{1+[f'(t)]^2}dt$$
>
> $$= \int_x^{1-\epsilon} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt\tag{2}$$
>
> To obtain the desired expression for $\mathscr{L}(x)$ we must then use
> the fact that
>
> $$\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0}\ (\text{length of }f\text{ on }
>  [x,1-\epsilon])=\text{ length of }f\text{ on }[x,1]\tag{3}$$
>
> This is proved as follows. First of all, the following figure shows
> that the "length of $f$ on $[x,1]$" does make sense; in fact, the
> length of $f$ on $[0,1]$ is $\leq 2$.
>
> [image]
>
> The same sort of figure also shows that the length of $f$ on
> $[1-\epsilon,1]$ is $\leq 2\epsilon$. The desired limit then follows
> from this inequality and the fact that
>
> $$\text{length of }f\text{ on } [x,1] = \text{ length of }f \text{ on
>  } [x,1-\epsilon]+\text{ length of }f\text{ on } [1-\epsilon,1]$$
>
> The proof of this latter fact is very similar to the corresponding
> assertion for integrals.

Let me try to interpret the assertions perhaps slightly more rigorously I hope.

The length of $f$ on $[x,1-\epsilon]$ is just a regular (ie, not improper) integral $\int_x^{1-\epsilon} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt$.

The length of $f$ on $[x,1]$ is the improper integral $\int_x^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt$.

We can write this integral as $$\int_x^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt=\int_x^{1-\epsilon} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt+\int_{1-\epsilon}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt\tag{4}$$

where $\int_{1-\epsilon}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt$ is the improper integral. But with a geometric argument we can see that this integral is both larger than $0$ and $<2\epsilon$

Now we take the limit of $(4)$ at $\epsilon \to 0$ we have

$$\int_x^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt=\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0} \left [ \int_x^{1-\epsilon} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt+\int_{1-\epsilon}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt\right ]\tag{5}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_x^{1-\epsilon} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt\tag{6}$$

At this point, what have we shown exactly? Don't we still have to show that this limit exists (by computing it in a simple way using $\arcsin$)?

Comment: It may be better if you can tell us what is the definition of "lentgth of $f$ on $[a,b]$". Btw, it seems that you said that "The length of $f$ on $[x,1]$ is the improper integral $\int_x^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt$", before the formula $(4)$, which is exactly waht we want to prove. That is circular. As a result, I have no idea on what you wanted to say since $(4)$.

Comment: As I recall, "the length of $f$" really means "The arclength of the graph of $y = f(x)$. Your criticism about "The length ... is the improper integral..." is correct; I'd suggest an edit of the form "We are interested in the improper integral <blah>; if it converges, then it is the arclength we seek."

Comment: I am just as confused as you are, to be honest. I am not sure what the problem is actually asking us to do, or what the proof did exactly. This is sort of what this question is all about. If we know that the length of the graph of a function $f$ on $[a,b]$ is defined $\int_a^b \sqrt{1+[f'(x)]^2}dx$, and $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ then don't we obtain the result we want immediately, namely that the length of the graph of $f$ on $[x,1]$ is $\int_x^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dt$?

Answer (score 1):

You are right: We must check that the limit $(6)$ exists. However, in your presentation you introduce the improper integral $\int_{1-\epsilon}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt$. This does not make sense unless you know that it exists. And even if you know that, it requires an argument that this integral is the length of $f$ on $[1-\epsilon,1]$. So let us go back.

For a continuous $f :[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ an a partition $P = (t_0,\ldots,t_n)$ of $[a,b]$ Spivak defines

$$\ell(f,P) =\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{(t_i-t_{i-1})^2 + (f(t_i) - f(t_{i-1}))^2} $$

If there exists an upper bound of all $\ell(f,P)$ for all partitions $P$, then the least upper bound is called the length of $f$ which we shall denote by $\ell(f)$. In an exercise Spivak asks to prove that if $f$ is differentiable and $f'$ is integrable, then $\ell(f)$ exists and is given by
$$\ell(f) = \int_a^b \sqrt{1 + f'(t)^2} dt$$

The problem here is that for $f(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ no derivation exists at $x = \pm1$ and moreover $f'(x)$ is not bounded on $(-1,1)$. Only on closed subintervals $[a,b] \subset (-1,1)$ we can say that $\ell(f \mid_{[a,b]})  = \int_a^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt$.

Thus we have to check first that the $\ell(f\mid_{[x,1]},P)$ are bounded above. Spivak gives a "graphical proof" (which can be easily formalized) that for $x \ge 0$ we always have
$$\ell(f \mid_{[x,1]},P) \le 2(1-x) . \tag{1}$$
One can easily check that $(1)$ also holds for $x \le 0$. Thus $\mathscr L(x)$ is well-defined for all $x \in [-1,1]$ with $\mathscr L(x) \le 2(1-x)$. It remains to compute $\mathscr L(x)$. To do so, we use the fact that for $x > -1$ we have
$$\mathscr L(x) = \ell(f \mid_{[x,1-\epsilon]}) + \mathscr L(1-\epsilon) .$$
Therefore
$$\lvert \mathscr L(x) - \ell(f \mid_{[x,1-\epsilon]}) \rvert = \mathscr L(1-\epsilon) \le 2\epsilon . \tag{2}$$
But
$$ \ell(f \mid_{[x,1-\epsilon]}) = \int_x^{1-\epsilon}  \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt = \arcsin(1-\epsilon) - \arcsin(x)\\ \to \arcsin(1) -  \arcsin(x) = \pi/2 - \arcsin(x) \text{ as } \epsilon \to 0.$$
Thus $(2)$ shows that
$$\mathscr L(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \ell(f \mid_{[x,1-\epsilon]}) = \pi/2 - \arcsin(x).$$

The case $x=-1$ can be treated by similar arguments using $\mathscr L(-1) = \ell(f \mid_{[0,\epsilon]}) + \mathscr L(\epsilon)$.